# Another prime inquiry: how many primes from 1 to *k*?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

With [the question I made about primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37363/prime-numbers-stretch-to-infinity-but-what-about-the-distance-between-them), I noticed people enjoy the subject, so here's another thought: let *k* be a positive integer; how many primes are there from 1 to *k*?

There's probably no exact expression for (let's call it) *N(k)* — and, unlike the other question, asking for $\lim_{k \to \infty} N(k)$ is silly because it's obviously infinity —, so, in a lenient variant of the question, does  *N(k)* asymptotically reach a certain function of *k* as it becomes larger?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: @Bill Dubuque That means the function I called $N$ is called $\pi$, and $\pi(k) \sim\! k / ln \space k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the well-known and well-studied prime-counting function, which you can read plenty about on its [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_counting_function).

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Prime Number Theorem.